Snowflake- IS there any way to generate a PDF report from snowflake table?
May be this question is not common, but i have requirement to convert/generate a pdf report from a snowflake table.
So is there any possible ways to do that?

You can create a python script to read data from a Snowflake table and write to a PDF file

We can do this in a similar to producing images, using Snowpark and signed URLs.
For more details, check my post "Hey Snowflake, send me a  HTML email" that sends images via email from Snowflake. I modified the code as seen above to generate PDFs:

https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-a-fancy-email-fe04ad2c9888

Working code:
create or replace procedure create_pdf_web_image(
    query_id string
    , title string)
returns string
language python
runtime_version = '3.11'
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'fpdf')
handler = 'run'
execute as caller
as
$$
import io
import pandas as pd
from fpdf import FPDF

class PDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, header_title):
        super().__init__()
        self._header_title = header_title
        
    def header(self):
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        self.cell(0, 10, self._header_title, 0, 1, 'C')

    def footer(self):
        self.set_y(-15)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        self.cell(0, 10, f'Page {self.page_no()}', 0, 0, 'C')

    def table(self, df):
        self.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
        col_width = self.w / (len(df.columns) + 1)
        row_height = self.font_size * 1.5

        for col_name in df.columns:
            self.cell(col_width, row_height, col_name, border=1)
        self.ln(row_height)

        for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
            for cell in row:
                self.cell(col_width, row_height, str(cell), border=1)
            self.ln(row_height)          

def save_file(session, buffer, path, dest_filename):
    session._conn.upload_stream(buffer, path, dest_filename, compress_data=False, overwrite=True)
    return path + '/' + dest_filename

def run(session, query_id, header):
    pdf = PDF(header)
    pdf.add_page()
    
    df = session.sql("select * from table(result_scan(?))", params=[query_id]).to_pandas()
    pdf.table(df)

    byte_string = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')
    binary_stream = io.BytesIO(byte_string)
  
    stage = '@pngstage'
    path = 'web_pdf'
    filename = 'pdf_%s.pdf' % (query_id)
    relative_path = save_file(session, binary_stream, stage + '/' + path, filename )
    return session.sql("select get_presigned_url(%s, '%s/%s', 604800) as url" % (stage, path, filename)).collect()[0]['URL']
$$
;

As a test:
select 1 a, 2 b;


call create_pdf_web_image('01b47d52-0504-af4f-001e-248302cf5b1e', 'The PDF header');


